# Grouping Radio buttons in CakePhp

Tags: cakephp, radio-button, radio-group

I have faced some confusion while creating some radio buttons in one page. Here i added the screen shot of the page.
[image]

Here there are five days.there are 4 other radio buttons corresponding to each days.
user can select only one day and corresponding 4 other radio buttons.
for example, if a user select Tuesday,then only he can able to select Tuesdays morning, evening, either carowner or commuter.
How we can group these radio buttons according to the above conditions?
if anyone knows about how to group these radio buttons..please help me.....
Thanx in advance....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i am just giving you logic to set for group in radio button

1) First of all you have to get id from length of selected radio button like morning in tuesday.

2) if you are getting id of tuesday so there will be some same index in day radio group for example tuesday has `1` index so on click event of morning radio button you must have to check is tuesday is checked or not if not then make uncheck morning of tuesday again uncheked.

similar for all remaing 3 (Evening,Car Owner, Communter) you can check

here i am just giving you example function to traverse radio button with its length or you can also find another function.

```
function checkRadioArray(radioButtons) { 
    for(var r=0;r < radioButtons.length; r++) { 
        if (radioButtons[r].checked) { 
        return true; // return id or index from here and check same index in first group of day.

    } 
} 
return false; 
}
```

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: can u explain the logic of that function..?i don't get it. the parameter radiobuttons?and length? how we get the length?
what id  we can give to each radio button...can u give me one example?

Comment: yes you can give same name to each radio button for example day radio button for same name so at time only one will select from day and you can get var len = document.frmOne.payment.length; and for loop like for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {

if ( document.frmOne.payment[i].checked ) {

payment = document.frmOne.payment[i].value;
break;

}

}

Comment: i got the logic..but not getting completely.first i write same name for all days so that i can select only one at a time.then what this statement means- var len = document.frmOne.payment.length?
and if i select one day.how we can select other radio buttons in that row?

Comment: ohh sorry to just mis understand but i thought that only one day at time is selected. but for that you have to give different name for all days if your consider to select each day. and then track parent radio button to check is selected or not. you can pass parameter as days name or day to check if selected day or not ?

Comment: can u please come for a chat??http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/31417/cakephp1-3?tab=general

Comment: can u please come for a chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31417/cakephp1-3